# UITabBarItem image above instead of beside text

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tabbar

[image]
How do i position the image on top of the text (like the first tab bar) for a tab bar item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you´re trying to change the position of the text, the image will follow the text. The best solution to solve your requirement is to:

1. Create custom `tabBar` images with the text places as you want
2. Remove the default text
3. Add your custom image to the `tabBar`